# Antilinear adjont of operator

Tags: functional-analysis

How to prove that the following statements are true?

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $C$ be a conjugation in $H$. Operator $T$ is linear and $X,Y$ are antilinear.

1. $(XT)^{\#}=T^{*}X^{\#}$
2. $(TX)^{\#}=X^{\#}T^*$
3. $(XY)^{*}=X^{\#}Y^{\#}$
4. $(X^{\#})^{\#}=X$
5. $(\alpha X+\beta Y)^{\#}=\overline{\alpha}X^{\#}+\overline{\beta}Y^{\#}$

I have:

- $T^{*}$ is adjoint of $T$ (a linear operator) if
  $\langle Tx,y \rangle = \langle x,T^{*}y \rangle$.
- $X^{\#}$ is antilinear adjoint of $X$(an antilinear operator) if
  $\langle Xx,y \rangle = \overline{\langle x,X^{\#}y \rangle}$.

Comment: Generally one should not post multiple problems in one post.  Even sharing a common setup (as here) is not a justification.  If the solution of one part of them is closely related to solving another one, and you can articulate that relation, then it would be allowed.  But you've seemingly not digested any of the parts, and instead simply presented them to Readers to do your thinking for you.  I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

It's just straightforward application of the definitions.

$$
\langle (XT)^\#x,y\rangle=\overline{\langle x,XTy\rangle}=\langle X^\#x,Ty \rangle=\langle T^*X^\#x,y\rangle.
$$
As this occurs for all $x,y$, you get $(XT)^\#=T^*X^\#$. The rest are similar.

Comment: Thank you  soo much